# Capture keyboard event CTRL+s

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

I need to fire an event by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

I tried this but it won't work:

```
if(e.ctrlKey == true && e.keyCode == 81){
        trace("CTRL+S")
    }
```

How can it be done? 
Thanks for tips.

Comment: Why aren't you using Keyboard constants? `e.keyCode==Keyboard.S` should do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is keyCode 83 for S (in case if you are making that mistake). Moreover, make sure you add your listener on KEY_UP event. Here is a working sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Panel title="Panel 3" width="100%" height="200" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
            private function onCreationComplete():void{
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
                this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyPressed);
            }

            private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                stage.focus = this;
            }

            private function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
                if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 65)
                    trace("CTRL A is pressed");
                if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 66)
                    trace("CTRL B is pressed");
                if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 81)
                    trace("CTRL S is pressed");
            }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
    </s:Panel>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: >>It is keyCode 83 for S - I think I need a break. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

M.D.'s answer looks very good; it shows how to add event listeners for the keyboard events.

But one thing he didn't mention: if you are running this as a Flash SWF in a browser, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut may be intercepted and consumed by the browser and the Flash Player may never get it. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is a pretty common shortcut for saving a page, so don't be surprised if you run into browser focus issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Which alternative shortcut would you suggest?

Comment: Allan is correct. For CTRL+S to work with Flex applications OR say flash movies, your Flex application should have focus on it. You can verify it like.. just launch your application, don't click anywhere and just do CTRL+S.

Comment: If you want to maximize compatibility across browsers and minimize focus issues, I'd suggest staying clear of ALT or CTRL key combos. SHIFT or no modifier at all both work very well, but that may not be usable if your app needs to allow typing. I guess a lot depends on what type of thing you are creating. For some use cases, it might make most sense to use a CTRL combo; just look at the expected browsers and avoid combos that they use.